# Ruby Sets: Creating instance variable does not clone set

Tags: ruby, set

As one would expect, when using basic data types, Ruby seems to create a copy of the variable when assigning it to an instance variable. In other words `@name` in the `Person` class does not point to `name`:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

name = "Michael"
p = Person.new(name)
name = "Peter"
puts p.name
=> "Michael"
```

If you do the same thing with sets, this no longer holds true. The instance variable `@family` points to `family` and all changes to `family` affect `@family`:

```
require 'set'

class Family
  attr_reader :people

  def initialize(people)
    @people = people
  end
end

people = Set.new ['Grandfather', 'Father', 'Mother', 'Son', 'Daughter']
family = Family.new(people)
people << 'Grandmother'
puts family.people.include? 'Grandmother'
=> true
```

Why is a Set behaving differently? And how do I best create a copy of family? (e.g. `@family = family.dup`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually...

> Ruby seems to create a copy of the variable when assigning it to an instance variable

is not true in the way that you think. Behold

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

name = "Michael"
p = Person.new(name)
name << " Jackson"
puts p.name
# "Michael Jackson"
```

Ruby is indeed a pass-by-value language, but those values are usually *pointers to objects*. Doing `name = "Peter"` doesn't affect the instance variable because you're just assigning a new pointer. If you use a method that modifies the object in-place (like `<<`) you *do* affect it because both variables store a pointer to the same object.

You are correct that the proper way to avoid this is to use `dup`.

Comment: So to be on the safe side, one should usually use .dup for instance variables?

Comment: I would say so. A big advantage of classes is encapsulation and sharing a pointer with some external variable would break that for most classes.